# Update and unset not working MongoDB and Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I am new to `MongoDB` and i am using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` package for build an API.

I am facing problem while updating and deleting a records in array.

Here is My code of update using foreach

```
foreach ($event->volunteers as $key => $volunteer) {
   if ($volunteer['user_id'] == $request->user_id) {
      $event->where('volunteers.user_id', $request->user_id)
          ->update(["volunteers.$key.attendance_status" => $request->attendance_status
                ]);
      }
}
```

Here is same code with Pull

```
 Event::where('volunteers.user_id', $request->user_id)->push('volunteers', [
            'attendance_status' => $request->attendance_status
            ], true);
```

Here is the code of unset

```
foreach ($event->volunteers as $key => $volunteer) {
            if ($volunteer['user_id'] == $request->user_id) {
                $event->where('volunteers.user_id', $request->user_id)
                    ->unset(
                        "volunteers.$key.attendance_status");
            }
        }
```

None of them are working

My DB structure is

```
 "volunteers" : [
    {
        "user_id" : NumberInt(1), 
        "name" : "Prafful K Panwar", 
        "skills" : [
            "Plumber", 
            "Carpenter"
        ], 
        "incentives" : {
            "tshirt_size" : "XXL"
        }, 
        "ready_to_contribute_min_amount" : "Yes", 
        "attendance_status" : false
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : NumberInt(2), 
        "name" : "Prafful Panwar", 
        "skills" : [
            "Plumber"
        ], 
        "incentives" : {
            "tshirt_size" : "XXL"
        }, 
        "ready_to_contribute_min_amount" : "Yes", 
        "attendance_status" : false
    }
]
```

Any advice, help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Change pull code to**

```
    Event::where('volunteers.user_id', $request->input('user_id'))->push('volunteers', ['attendance_status' => $request->input('attendance_status')
                ], true);
```

**Change unset code to**

```
    $userId = $request->input('user_id');

    foreach ($event->volunteers as $key => $volunteer) {
        if ($volunteer['user_id'] == $userId) {
            $event->where('volunteers.user_id', $userId)
                ->unset("volunteers.$key.attendance_status");
        }
    }
```